# Can a function return an argument that is a restrict pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, restrict-qualifier

Say I have a function that takes 2 non-aliased `int*`, and copies one `int` into the other, then returns the `int*` that served as the destination.
For example:

```c
int* copy_int(int* restrict dest, int const* restrict src) {
    *dest = *src;
    return dest;
}
```

Is any of the following calling code undefined behaviour?

```c
void caller(void) {
    int dest;
    int src = 42;

    copy_int(&dest, &src);  // ignored return value aliases &dest
}
```

```c
void caller(void) {
    int dest;
    int src = 42;

    int* dest_addr = copy_int(&dest, &src);  // dest_addr aliases &dest
}
```

```c
void caller(void) {
    int dest;
    int src = 42;

    int* dest_addr = &dest;
    int* dest_addr_2 = copy_int(&dest, &src);  // dest_addr_2 aliases dest_addr
}
```

Or am I safe to assume that `restrict` only applies inside the callee, and that I can alias those pointers outside the function call?

Comment: FWIW, the formal definition of `restrict` is in section 6.7.3.1 of the C standard. Another point of interest is that your `copy_int` function has a similar signature, and the same return behavior (returning the destination pointer) as the standard library function `memcpy`. I've never heard of any limits on the use of the return value from `memcpy`.

Comment: @user3386109 yes, it is simillar. On that note, why doesn't `memcpy` have restrict qualifier on its parameters? The documentation states that the memory areas must not overlap, which is even a stricter requirement.

Comment: The signature of `memcpy` per section 7.24.2.1 of the C11 specification is `void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, const void * restrict s2, size_t n);` Which is to say that it *does* have the restrict qualifier on its parameters.

Comment: You're right, I just checked the standard.
My pc's man pages aren't accurate, strange. Maybe because it wasn't restrict qualified up until C99?

Comment: @no_stupid_questions The next release of the man pages will add `restrict` to the prototypes of functions that use it.  It was recently added in a patch set of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`restrict` applies to inside `copy_int(int* restrict dest, int const* restrict src)` in what the function can assume - leading to better optimized code.  The caller is obliged to pass addresses that do not overlap data.

All cases do the same thing in that regard: `copy_int(&dest, &src);`.  `dest` and `src` are not aliasing each other.  The aliasing cases presented by OP do not affect `dest, src`.

Example of bad code below.

```
copy_int(&src, &src);  // bad
```